# How much power will a 4kW BLDC motor use if ran for 3 hours?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, power-consumption

My college is participating in a competition to build a solar car with batteries. After doing calculations, we have decided on using a 72V, 4000W BLDC motor.

Now, we need to run the vehicle for 250km within 7 hours. The torque produced by the motor is rated for continuous 30Nm at 1000rpm drawing 100A current, and around 5Nm at 3000rpm drawing 10A current.

Now, the EV should be able to run at 100kmph while spinning at 3000rpm, and I want to figure out how much energy would be consumed over the approx. 3hr of run time, so that we could select an appropriate battery.

Can this be calculated simply by finding the force acting against the vehicle (air and friction), and multiplying it with the running speed of 100kmph and the time it runs (3 hours)? Is there another way to find this?

Comment: If it still has power Answer : 4kW  otherwise 0

Comment: Jameel, you're confusing power and energy. The moment you look up how power and energy are related, the question should answer itself.

Comment: Welcome to the site. From the parmeters you listed, I would say, as you said too, 72V * 10A * 3hr = 2,160 Wh + enough_margin is good. BTW, Don't go on a major highway.

Comment: The first question is, with your chosen gearing, what torque do you need to sustain 100km/h (and 3000rpm)?

Comment: Your figures are not fully consistent. |Mechanica Watts `= Nm X RPM / 10 OR Kg.m X RPM. AND Electrical watts = V X I AND air drag watts = 0.6 X A X V_cubed X CD. || A in m^2, V in m/s. Cd of 0.1 for a solar car is goodish and 0.05 or v slightly less has been achieved. Try all those figures. There are losses along the way so Pelec > Pmotorout >Pdrag.

Comment: One approach is to figure out how much power you need to run at a particular speed (using aerodynamic drag and tire friction on the ground, etc).  Divide that by 0.75 (assuming 75 percent efficiency from battery to road). That is how much output power you need. Multiply by hours and that is how many Watt hours you need. Or you could build up the car, run it at speed and measure the battery current. That will be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Can you measure current and voltage at 100kph to get a data point? You could then validate that against any aerodynamic and friction model you develop.

Since you measured the motor at a given torque (I assume you have a dynamometer) you can also estimate efficiency from that. (Did you measure this through the controller? It has losses too.)

As a ballpark figure, 90% is typical for a battery discharge (dissipated as heating), and about 80% for the power train controller, motor and mechanical losses, so you get about 72% overall (criticism / feedback welcomed here.)

So then you can build a model for power vs. speed based on rolling friction and drag, then divide by efficiency to obtain power consumed at any given point on your road course. Piecewise-integrate that over your entire course run time and you get energy consumed.

One more thing (ok, two more): is your course flat, and does your controller support regeneration? You’ll need to model that too.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that we can ignore the work done by the motor during the initial acceleration to the cruising speed of 100km/h, and that the vehicle will remain at this speed for the remainder of the 250km trip.

I'll also assume you've experimentally determined the (average) forces of resistance present at that speed. Those forces combined, at cruising speed where we are not accelerating or decelerating, must be equal to the forward driving force \$F_{AVG}\$, at the point of contact between the wheels and the ground.

The work done by the motors is the integral over the entire 250km course of \$F \cdot ds\$ (where \$F\$ is driving force and \$s\$ is the distance travelled), but in the absence of a well defined function \$F(s)\$, you must rely on your estimated average force. At 72% efficiency, work done by the batteries will be:

$$ E = \frac{F_{AVG} \times 250km}{0.72} $$

Average battery output power will be

$$ P_{AVG} = \frac{E}{7 \times 3600s} = \frac{F_{AVG} \times 250km}{0.72 \times 25000s}$$

This expression doesn't explicitly refer to speed, but the term \$\frac{250km}{25000s}\$ does, in fact, equal average speed. Your proposed formula is correct, without accounting for efficiency.

It also doesn't refer to the motor's characteristics at all, because this simple truth of physics is independent of the means by which the energy is actually delivered. Motor characteristics will play a role in determining efficiency, but not in work done getting the vehicle from A to B.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what to do. I found the current flowing at each rpm range and used it to find the power. After that, some more calculations to decide on the wattage of solar panels to use and battery capacities.